# Python - create a dictionary from a folder directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve a problem but a little bit confusing.

What i want to do, is to create a dictionary object that contains a directory folders and their files as **childrens**, something like this one:

```
vm.folder = {
    id: 'root',
    name: 'Root',
    type: "folder",
    children: [
        {
            id: "Folder 1",
            name: "1",
            type: "folder",
            children: [
                {
                    id: "Folder 1a",
                    name: "1a",
                    type: "folder",
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: "1a1",
                            name: "1a1",
                            type: "file"
                        },
                        {
                            id: "1a2",
                            name: "1a2",
                            type: "file"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The code that i have here is getting just the dirname and the filename assigning them to dictionary as keys and values:

```
def pathto_dict(path):
    file_token = ''
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        tree = {dir: pathto_dict(os.path.join(root, dir)) for dir in dirs}
        tree.update({file: file_token for file in files})
        return tree
```

Comment: Please add the following: The actual directory structure you are dealing with, the actual output you are getting, and a plain python tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the attached code. It does not include the id attribute that you specified, but that could be easily added in the `tree = {}` part of the code.

```
def pathto_dict(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_):
        tree = {"name": root, "type":"folder", "children":[]}
        tree["children"].extend([pathto_dict(os.path.join(root, d)) for d in dirs])
        tree["children"].extend([{"name":os.path.join(root, f), "type":"file"} for f in files])
        return tree
```

Comment: I just wanted to use `extend()` !!!, what a shame!!! now i understand it completely , thank you it worked :)